# How to use click event on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I generate many bootstrap modals with a php script, and I'd like to edit some input of it when I click button "save changes".
ModalIDs generated are something like "ModalID0000".
But nothing happens with my script when i click on "save changes".

```
        <input role="button" data-target="#modalID<?php echo $post->Clone;?>" />
        
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalID<?php echo $post->Clone;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Identifiants" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Identifiants de connexion</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- mdp et user récupérés dans le champ commentaire, sinon standard -->
                    <?php if ($flagLogin == true){ ?>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/>
                    <input type="password" value="<?php echo $pwd; ?>"/>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <input class="user_login" type="text" value="user"/>
                    <input class="user_password" type="password" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue-grey z-depth-0" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning z-depth-0 save" >Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
    $("modal.save").click(function(){ 
            alert('save');
            //edit user_login and user_password values here  
    });
```

EDIT :
1st mistake found with modal element selector instead of class, but still no alert

```
    $(".modal.save").click(function(){ 
            alert('save');
    });
```

Comment: you might need to use ajaxs here to send data to another php file to save data.

Comment: check your target name `$("modal.save")` from the code, I can't see anything with classname 'save' also, modal needs to be a class instead of element.

Comment: @Amyth the 2nd button got save class.

Comment: @Nosfé - your selector $("model.save") is not targetting the button. Can you try `$(".modal .save")` instead?

Comment: @kunz I only want to edit input values if user need to, then use a php to do my data processing

Comment: hmm i do not seem to understand your question

Comment: @Nosfé ah, was not in the view, but the 2nd part is true, modal selector needs to be class and not element. Cheers

Comment: @kunz When my modal shows up, I want to edit user_login and user_password values  input using "Saves changes" button (and close modal in same way). But it seems I dont success to call jquery function from it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Save` button is the child element of `.modal` selector.

So `$("modal.save")` should be replaced to `$(".modal .save")`.

Or that button belongs to `.modal-footer` so you can put as follows.

```
$(".modal-footer .save")
```

```js
$(".modal .save").click(function () {
  alert('save');
  //edit user_login and user_password values here  
});
```

```html
<input role="button" data-target="#modalID<?php echo $post->Clone;?>" />

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalID<?php echo $post->Clone;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="Identifiants" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Identifiants de connexion</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- mdp et user récupérés dans le champ commentaire, sinon standard -->
        <?php if ($flagLogin == true){ ?>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" />
        <input type="password" value="<?php echo $pwd; ?>" />
        <?php } else { ?>
        <input class="user_login" type="text" value="user" />
        <input class="user_password" type="password" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue-grey z-depth-0" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning z-depth-0 save">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and if it's not working, pls try with `$(".modal-footer .save")`

Comment: Not better with `$(".modal-footer .save")` selector.

Comment: Have you seen the code snippet? It works well with no issues. To catch your issue, it is needed to check the rest codes too.

Comment: Yes, your snippet works, but I use ajax to call my php script that generate all my modals, and it still not working. Is there something about the scope maybe ?

Comment: So this means, you get the modal html content using `ajax` request? If then, when making buttons, you can simply add `onclick` event there with defined javascript functions.

Comment: Yes, you get it. I've already tried onclick, and it works, but I heard it's better to avoid calling function with it.

Comment: But in your case, that modal is not existed and it's dynamically generated by the ajax call so it's better to use `onclick` instead of `jquery`.

Comment: Can you approve my answer if it helped?